# ExtJS 4.0 Find data in model and treepanel

Tags: extjs, treepanel

With the following Json I populate a treepanel:

```
[{"text":"Item 1}", "expanded":true, "cls":"folder", "children":
    [{"text":"Item 1.1", "leaf":true, "foo", "bar"},
    ...
...
```

When the user selects Item 1.1 in the tree I'm able to find the selected Item:

```
onTreepanelSelectionChange: function(tablepanel, selections, options) {
    var selItem = selections[0].data.text;
```

So I have access to properties like **text**, **expanded**, ... But I can't find a way to access the value of **foo**. I think my problem is caused by the fact that I find the selected item via the treepanel and that the value of **foo** is only available in the store.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `foo` property to your model.

Comment: Thanx, I actually need this mantra: 'all is object all is object all is object'.